# Change rails value with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to change a rails value with ajax and I am having trouble. Here is what I have so far.

ajax

```
$(button).click(function(){
        $.ajax({
           url: '/change_value',
           type: 'GET'
    })
});
```

Controller

```
def home
  @value = 0
end

def change_value
  @value = 1
end
```

routes

```
get '/change_value', to: 'static_pages#change_value'
```

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: please paste your .js.erb file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a view to respond in `js` format:

change_value.js.erb

```
var newValue = <%= @value %>;
```

Now, use it in your script:

```
$(button).click(function(){
        $.ajax({
           url: '/change_value',
           type: 'GET',
           success: function(data) {
               console.log(newValue);
           }
    })
});
```